# SLSvcUtil generates RequestObject

Tags: silverlight, wcf, slsvcutil

i´ve recently created a WCF-Service and would like to consume it with a Silverlight App. To do so, i used SlSvcUtil (Silverlight 4) to create the necessary client-Side Classes. 
But for every Method, this tool generates a Request-Object wich has properties for all Parameters the Method usually takes

```
public System.IAsyncResult BeginDepartmentGetAll(DepartmentGetAllRequest request,    System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        object[] _args = new object[1];
        _args[0] = request;
        System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("DepartmentGetAll", _args, callback, asyncState);
        return _result;
    }

public System.IAsyncResult BeginDummy(DummyRequest request, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        object[] _args = new object[1];
        _args[0] = request;
        System.IAsyncResult _result = base.BeginInvoke("Dummy", _args, callback, asyncState);
        return _result;
    }
```

The corresponding Request Classes look like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "Dummy", WrapperNamespace ="http://example.com/Namespace", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class DummyRequest
```

{

```
[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://example.com/Namespace", Order = 0)]
public string s;

public DummyRequest()
{
}

public DummyRequest(string s)
{
    this.s = s;
}
```

}

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "DepartmentGetAll", WrapperNamespace = "http://example.com/Namespace", IsWrapped = true)]
public partial class DepartmentGetAllRequest
{
   public DepartmentGetAllRequest()
   {
   }
}
```

In a similar WCF-Project these methods take the plain Parameters of the Web-Service Method, without using a Request-Object. How can I generate the Service-Methods without these Request Objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the puzzle:

Wether slsvcutil generates these mysterious request objects or not depends on the ServiceContractAttribute.

If you set:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface MyService {
    [OperationContract]
    void MyMethod(Guid id);
}
```

the corresponding Client Method looks like this:

```
service.BeginMyMethod(id);
```

But if you set:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://example.com/MyService")]
public interface MyService {
    [OperationContract]
    void MyMethod(Guid id);
}
```

it looks like this:

```
service.BeginMyMethod(new MyMethodRequest(id));
```